# MongoDB - Update all documents NOT returned in aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, python, mongodb-3.4

I'm using PyMongo to write a Mongo update script. I have an aggregate query which returns a sum of all searches performed by each user in the last 30 days:

```
cursor = mongo_search_logs_collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "created": {"$gte": datetime(search_count_start_date.year, search_count_start_date.month,
                                         search_count_start_date.day)},
            "primarySearch": True
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$createdBy", "searchCount": {"$sum": 1}
        }
    }
])
```

I would like to iterate over all documents NOT included in the aggregate query results from above, and set their `searchCount` to zero. Is there an easy/clean way to do that?

I tried simply iterating over all users, checking if a user exists in the list of users returned by the aggregate, and then updating each search count accordingly, but this is taking a LONG time...I'd prefer a faster way of doing it if possible.

Comment: You can do the entire process within the aggregation only. Here is a similar post: [Group records by month and count them - Mongoose, nodeJs, mongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61051225/group-records-by-month-and-count-them-mongoose-nodejs-mongodb/61062406#61062406).

Comment: @prasad_ But how do I tell an aggregate query to return only documents which are *not* part of the aggregate I posted? Also, is there a way to bulk update a specific field in the documents returned by the aggregate or am I stuck iterating over the cursor?

Comment: (1) See this post: [Partition data around a match query during aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285951/partition-data-around-a-match-query-during-aggregation/60292537#60292537), it allows to get sum for two conditions, like your case. First case is with the match condition and the second case is other than those in the case 1 match condition. Also, there are two approaches of aggregation in the same post. (2) The aggregation result can be used to update documents in a batch using [Bulk Write Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/index.html).

Comment: @prasad_ I appreciate it but that's not at all what I'm trying to do. I just need to know how to negate the match, i.e. return everything that *doesn't* match the conditions of the aggregate

Comment: There is a `$not` operator. Also, if your data set has `[ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]`, and the match returns `[ "a", "c" ]`, then the difference between these two arrays (or sets) gives the not matched: [ "b", "d" ]. You can use the aggregation set operators, for example the `$setDifference`.